# ui-bootstrap pagination works fine outside ng-view but not in ng-view

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, pagination

I want to apply ui-bootstrap pagination on ng-repeat on one of my datatable. It works fine when table is outside of ng-view but when it's inside ng-view filters and sorting works fine and pagination gives following error.

**Template for directive 'pagination' must have exactly one root element. template/pagination/pagination.html**

I'm using spring rest services at backend.

```
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
```

These are the files that I've included.

Controller code is

```
controller("FileController", function($window, $scope, $location) {


$scope.order = function (predicate) {  
  $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;  
  $scope.predicate = predicate;  
};  

$scope.paginate = function (value) {  
  var begin, end, index;  
  begin = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage;  
  end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;  
  index = $scope.fileList.indexOf(value);  
  return (begin <= index && index < end);  
};
```

});

and pagination tag in html is

```
<pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage"  
                                     max-size="10" boundary-links="true"  
                                     items-per-page="numPerPage" class="pagination-sm">  
                               </pagination>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, [see this documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt).

I can't see your code, but I guess your directive template contains more than one root element.

so in the principle, instead of doing

```
<head>

</head>
<body>

</body>
```

Do

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify your included CSS and JS. Also observe your browser console for error.

I have created sample will give you more insight.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/685gdbao/1/)

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="about.html">
    <h1>About TODO</h1>
    <h4>{{todos.length}} total</h4>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="todo in filteredTodos">{{todo.text}}</li>
    </ul>
    <pagination 
      ng-model="currentPage"
      total-items="todos.length"
      max-size="maxSize"  
      boundary-links="true">
    </pagination>
</script>
```